# Fire a CustomEvent from element in dom-repeat

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, dom-repeat

Hello I have this issue with a dom-repeat template. I have an element with a dom-repeat and inside I'm showing a my-item element, I have a button that fired a custom event and I need to get that event in the parent element but I can't make it work. Any thoughts on this? Why I never get `updateFired(e)` called?

> Element: my-view

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{employees}}">
      <my-item employee="[[item]]" on-update="updateFired"></my-item>
    </template>
    updateFired(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
```

> Element: my-item

```
<div class="container">
        <div>First name: <span>[[employee.first]]</span></div>
        <div>Last name: <span>[[employee.last]]</span></div>
        <button on-click="testClick">Click</button>
    </div>
    testClick(e) {
        const event = new CustomEvent('onUpdate', { bubbles: true, composed: true, detail: this.employee });
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the way you wrote the event handler your event name should be "**update**", not "**onUpdate**". The `on-` prefix is added just for defining the event handler, the actual event name should be the part after it.

So you would need to change

```
const event = new CustomEvent('onUpdate', { bubbles: true, composed: true, detail: this.employee });
```

to

```
const event = new CustomEvent('update', { bubbles: true, composed: true, detail: this.employee });
```

Comment: @JoseRaulPerera you are welcome, I am glad it helps. Also you can note that you need to provide the flags `bubbles` and `composed` for the event to "escape" the shadow DOM boundaries, but in this way that you're listening for it you are actually getting an event that happens *inside* `my-item`, so your code should work even without them, just with the *detail* provided. Since you're not stopping the propagation in `my-view` it might be a good idea to have it stop there instead of bubbling it up to the top level (that is if you don't need it above, ofc)

Comment: thanks, I will remove this so we don't have performance issues or memory leaks in the app. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

On your HTML do something like:

```
<div id="foo" style="width:20px;height:20px;background-color:#ffcc00;" onclick="javascript:updateFired(event)"></div>
```

And in your javascript:

```
const el = document.getElementById('foo');
el.onclick = showFoo;


function showFoo() {
  alert('Clicked!');
}
```

Comment: Those would be two different ways to attach a "regular" click handler in vanilla JS with no shadowDom involved. But the question is about Polymer, custom elements and how events can be listened for from "outside"..

Comment: Thanks @Tiago Machado yes for Polymer it doesn't work

Comment: sorry :/ I will try to figure out